# Change SharePoint 2013 License from Enterprise to MSDN Enterprise possible?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, licensing

I have a development server that has been installed as a full fledged enterprise server with Enterprise SQL and also Enterprise SharePoint.

This should be changed to a MSDN environment.

My question is. Can I change license key in the SharePoint server from the Enterprise license gotten from Volume Licensing Center to a MSDN license?

Comment: If it's compliance you're concerned about, I wouldn't be too worried.  At last check Microsoft only cares that you possess both licenses for your SharePoint installation, and won't care too much if they're on the wrong servers.  So if you can point to a production server, and the relevant license.  Then a development server and relevant license, you're in the clear.  Feel free to counter me though everyone.

Answer (score 2):

With an account who is member of The Farm Admin SP Group you can browse to `http://centralAdminURL:port/_admin/Conversion.aspx` or click Upgrade and Migration > Convert farm license type and add your new license key.

[image]

Now this is disabled by default and you have to use the developer tool to enable it. Clicking the input field, you'll see the disabled attribute. Change its name to something else (adding a few characters will do). Enter your license key, and turn your developer tool pointer to the OK button and do the same thing there.

[image]

This is probably not supported, and I'd advice you not to use this in production. But it's worth a try in your development environment.

Reference: [How to Enable the convert License type option Under Upgrade and Migration](http://expertsharepoint.blogspot.se/2013/11/issue-convert-license-type-is-grayed-out.html).

Comment: Have you tried writing in that field? I only see a disabled field and disabled button.
You can work around this however. But I dont know the ramifications of actually editin this way.

You can edit the HTML of the input field and button tag in the conversion.aspx via developer tools in the browser and change the disabled parameter to make it editable. 

    `<input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$BtnSectionBottom$RptControls$BtnOkBottom" tabindex="1" class="aspNetDisabled" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_BtnSectionBottom_RptControls_BtnOkBottom" accesskey="o" type="submit" value="OK" *cc*="disabled">`

Comment: @KjetilYtrehus There is a workaround. See the updated answer.

Comment: Your updated answer is MY comment! And I just wrote that I dont know the ramifications of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge and experience, it is really does not matter what CD key is being used in the SharePoint. In SharePoint key is not recoverable as compare to other products like office. As you want to move from VL to MSDN, So if you

- As long as your SharePoint being used for the development purpose and you will provide the license to MSFT, you will all set.

But if you still want to change it, then you need alot of effort.

- Rebuild the farm using the new key.
- or directly update the database with new key but this method put you unsupported.

Comment: What do you mean by provinding the license to MSFT? 

I have a powershell script to recover the key used if that is what you mean.

Rebuilding the farm is what Im afraid that i have to do. Even though I know how to change it in the database kinda.

Comment: I am not aware if you can recover it, we tried this long time ago...when we perform an audit on the developer machine but could not get. then later MSFT audit we just give them the MSDN license for each developer and they all set.

Comment: You can recover a SharePoint enterprise license with PowerShell. I have done this procedure myself before.