# Activate a new license key

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise, license

We are running SharePoint 2013 with MSDN Subscription(Enterprise Version) and we want to change it to full Enterprise.Is it possible to update the Product Key from MSDN Enterprise to Enterprise?

I saw few articles but none were recommend approach.Can someone help me with a recommended approach?

Please note this is for Production environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conclusion after lot of Analysis:

Though there is no straight forward path/approach to update the product key, there are workarounds for the same. See below link

Using CA - [Change SharePoint 2013 License from Enterprise to MSDN Enterprise possible?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140490/change-sharepoint-2013-license-from-enterprise-to-msdn-enterprise-possible)

Using SQL/CA - http://thesharepointfarm.com/2012/05/so-you-want-to-enter-a-new-product-key-this-is-unsupported/

But these workaround are not recommended for production environment.

From the analysis I made, rebuilding the server seems to be the recommended approach to update the product key(if required).

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/81cac564-c880-49d8-8c92-d8e83810e3f4/change-license-key-from-enterprise-to-education-enterprise?forum=sharepointadmin

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6331f353-2cfa-49f2-91c0-d8a7f993602d/sharepoint-2013-update-product-key?forum=sharepointadmin&prof=required

Microsoft don't care if the SharePoint farm has been installed with an MSDN license key or the one that you got when you paid for the license. If they do an audit they'll be interested in how many servers you have and how many licenses you have and that's all.

There is no need to try to switch the keys. Don't bother, it's a waste of time and only adds risk to your platform.

Answer (score 3):

Better reinstall the farm and migrate data. Backup/restore can help.
If it's not possible, talk to your Microsoft contact.
Write emails or even official letters to have a record for later just in case.
ServerFault has a nice canonical question on this matter - https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue

I don't think that even running SP under MSDN license in production environment is legal

Comment: http://www.sharepointsapiens.com/blog/how-to-install-and-activate-a-new-license-key                                                                                                    Is this a recommended approach?

Comment: Hi. That's a third-party solution, not SharePoint

Answer (score 1):

With an account who is member of The Farm Admin SP Group you can go to http://centralAdminURL:port/_admin/Conversion.aspx

[image: Sharepoint admin]

Update: this seems to disabled by default. Check [this article](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140490/change-sharepoint-2013-license-from-enterprise-to-msdn-enterprise-possible) to enable it.

Comment: thanks for your reply.In the above article to enable the product key text box,it is updated as a not supported approach for production.