# Do I need to rebuild the farm just to reenter the key?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, licensing

We've installed SharePoint 2010 SP2 Enterprise using the MSDN key. For some reason, I thought I could easily change it later. However, to my horror I've learned that I cannot do it.

So, the question is this: Can I leave this key as soon as the customer actually paid for the license? What if the customer is audited? Will be there any problems with the key? Or MS does not care about it as soon as you paid?

P.S. We don't want to do anything that is not supported by MS like chaining the key in SQL, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activate a new license key](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/169105/activate-a-new-license-key)

Comment: Yes, it looks like a duplicate. But it's not. I'm not asking how to change the key, but what will happen during the audit when it comes.

Comment: Question poster there ended up with (citing) *there is no need to try to switch the keys. Don't bother, it's a waste of time and only adds risk to your platform* and provided some links. That might be worth linking to this question for future researchers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there is no way to change the key without reinstalling the farm.

Having said that, the keys that Microsoft hands out for SharePoint are static keys, i.e. they do not change between customers. I realise that you've used an MSDN key rather than a volume key (and these *are* different), however as long as the customer has purchased the correct licenses, there shouldn't be an issue.

To be sure, the customer should check with their license provider that this is not going to cause them an issue should they be audited.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use software from MSDN for production purposes given you have the proper licensing for it. This is outlined on the [Visual Studio 2015 Licensing Whitepaper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350).

> Using Software Sourced from Subscriber Downloads but Licensed Under a Production License
>
> Often, it is more expedient to deploy a server running a fully-tested application directly into production. Normal licenses
> must be acquired for this use (such as a Windows Server license and Client Access Licenses) because the Visual Studio
> subscription license is per user and is generally limited to development and testing. However, the installed software and
> the product key used to activate that software, where applicable, can be from Subscriber Downloads, even though the
> licenses to use that software in production must be acquired separately from the Visual Studio subscription.